# How to inform Nutch to avoid crawling list of websites

Tags: web-crawler, nutch

I am using Apache nutch 2.2.1. My crawler is crawling whole web i.e. no filter is applied. I have few websites that I want not to be crawled by nutch forever.

How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in Apache nutch configuration directory, there is a file name regex-urlfilter.txt. That will do the job what you are looking for. For example, if you have to block a website http://wiki.thm.com then you write following in above file

```
-^(http|https)://http://wiki.thm.com.*$
```

For further please study [Nutch wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/FrontPage).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried entering specific "seed URLs" into the configuration, e.g. http://my.site.to/crawl (replace by something more useful)

There should be a config file called "seed.txt" in the folder /conf/urls.

Comment: yes, definately, I have a seed.txt file. But in this case nutch will also follow outlinks that I also want. In this way my seed will grow. But only few websites are ristricted to be crawled

Comment: In the config file NUTCH_HOME/conf/nutch-default.xml there is a switch to ignore outgoing links. look for this property: <property>
  <name>db.ignore.external.links</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, outlinks leading from a page to external hosts
  will be ignored. This is an effective way to limit the crawl to include
  only initially injected hosts, without creating complex URLFilters.
  </description>
</property>

Comment: I think you do not understand my comments. I said I have to follow outlinks also. I have to block  just few websites

Comment: I am sorry, I misunderstood. For blocking specific websites there are several examples to be found here: https://scm.thm.de/pharus/nutch-config/source/66fba7d3dc015974b5c194e7ba49da60fe3c3199:Nutch-Config/conf/regex-urlfilter.txt  probably lines 71ff. fits best to what you described.